# Software & updates won't open. Possibly downloaded something for 14.10 on accident somehow

Tags: 14.04, software-center, system-settings

I can't open "Software and updates" in 14.04 LTS. I've tried multiple restarts and unplugging and replugging various USB devices (I read that somewhere, sounded silly but couldn't hurt to try!) and it still won't open.

After doing many Google searches, as wording software and updates is tough to do there, I saw the command `software-properties-gtk` and ran it. I got:

```
>>$software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 101, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 98, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/utopic
```

From what I understand (not much), I somehow got a hold of a 14.10 file in there? I feel like uninstalling and reinstalling the program would work, but as I said earlier: I have no idea what I'm doing yet and this particular program is very hard to phrase in Google to get a relevant answer =).

I could just reinstall the OS, but I am on a crappy 10GB/month data plan (rural area, only option other than 56k) and my roommate would be pretty upset. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that your distribution did not got changed by mistake in lsb-release.

You can do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

And it should look like that: (if not change it and save)

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

Also check the version in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
Change any `utopic` appearing in this file into `trusty`.